# how to call a function from another component in vue3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

i have tried to using `$on` method and `this.$root.$refs.compname_component = this;` but got some errors,Please refer below my codes

formComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <div v-if="showForm">
    create Form
  </div>
</template>
<script>

export default {
  props:[],
  setup(props) {
    return props;
  },
  data() {
    return {
      formData:{},
      showForm:false
    }
  },
  created() {
    // this.$root.$refs.tableCommon = this;
    // this.$root.$refs.compname_component = this;

  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('form mounted');
    // this.$root.$on("displayForm", () => {
    //   this.displayForm();
    // });

  },
  methods: {
    displayForm:function(){
      this.showForm = true;
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

commonComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="col-10 text-end custom-inline-spacing mb-3">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" @click="showCreateForm">Create</button>
    </div>

</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: [],
  setup() {
    return {}
  },
  data() {
    return {
      
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('mounted common')
  },
  methods: {
    showCreateForm : function(){
      // this.$refs.form.displayForm();
      // this.$root.$refs.compname_component.displayForm();
      // this.$root.$emit("displayForm");
      this.createForm.displayForm();
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap')


import { createApp } from 'vue'
import tableCommon from './components/CommonComponent'
import createForm from './components/formComponent';

const app = createApp({})

app.component('vue-common', tableCommon);
app.component('create-form', createForm);

app.mount('#app')
```

actualy what i want means call `formComponent.displayForm()` from CommonComponent.

Comment: you should usually communicate via events over the parent component or for more complex scenarios you could share some state (e.g. via vuex or with outsourced Vue3 composition API variables) or use an event bus.

Comment: As **ssc-hrep3** suggested - using an event bus is the optimal choice. It prevents the needless coupling between the 2 components in your usecase.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to conditionally display child component, you can move logic out of that component into the parent component.

Parent.vue

```
<template>
    <FormComponent v-if="showComponent" />
</template>
```

Alternatively, you can pass a prop into FormComponent if you need to conditionally display only a part of that component.

Parent.vue

```
<template>
    <FormComponent v-bind:show-component="showComponent" />
</template>
```

FormComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <div v-if="showComponent">
        ...
    </div>
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
</template>
```